# Linq simple query returns unexpected results

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have configured my connection to DB as follows:

Web.config

```
<add name="MyContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=MyServer;Initial Catalog=MyDB;User id=MyId;Password=MyPassword; MultipleActiveResultSets=true" />
```

Then I have my class to create context in order to access Database

```
    public class MyContext: DbContext
    {
        public MyContext() : base("MyContext")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<Models.MyContext>(null);
        }

        public DbSet<MyModel> MyTable { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }
    }
}
```

Then I have my DB with table 'MyTable', which is a history table, so every day at 6:00 I am inserting data from another table, finally I will have results like this

```
Id | Date
-----------------------------
 1 | 2018-05-30 16:01:00.332
 1 | 2018-05-31 14:21:03.456
 1 | 2018-06-01 11:45:01.316
 2 | 2018-05-30 21:44:00.544
 2 | 2018-05-31 22:45:00.987
 2 | 2018-06-01 23:46:00.769
```

So now in MyController.cs

```
    public IQueryable<MyModel> GetData(string Id)
    {
        var result = MyContext.MyTable.AsQueryable();

        return result.Where(w => w.Id == Id).toList();
    }
```

I am trying to return all rows for Id = 1, on debugging when I set a breakpoint in the return statement, it returns the same row, for every record.

```
    Id | Date
    -----------------------------
     1 | 2018-05-30 16:01:00.332
     1 | 2018-05-30 16:01:00.332
     1 | 2018-05-30 16:01:00.332
```

Edit: I add MyModel class as you requested

```
 public class MyModel
    {
        [Index(IsUnique = false)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date{ get; set; }

        public string Field1 { get; set; }
        public string Field2 { get; set; }
        public string Field3 { get; set; }
        public string Field4 { get; set; }
        public string Field5 { get; set; }
        public string Field6 { get; set; }
        public string Field7 { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Field8 { get; set; }
        public string Field9 { get; set; }
        public string Field10 { get; set; }
        public string Field11 { get; set; }
        public string Field12 { get; set; }
        public string Field13 { get; set; }
        public string Field14 { get; set; }
        public string Field15 { get; set; }
        public string Field16 { get; set; }
        public string Field17 { get; set; }
        public string Field18 { get; set; }
        public string Field19 { get; set; }
        public int? Field20 { get; set; }
        public string Field21 { get; set; }
        public int? Field22  { get; set; }
        public int? Field23 { get; set; }
        public int? Field24  { get; set; }
        public string Field25 { get; set; }
        public string Field26 { get; set; }
        public string Field27 { get; set; }
        public int Field28 { get; set; }
        public string Field29 { get; set; }
        public string Field30 { get; set; }
        public string Field31 { get; set; }
        public string Field32 { get; set; }
        public string Field33 { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Field34 { get; set; }

    }
```

Can you help me to figure out what's going on?

Thanks.

Comment: can you do `result.Where(w => w.Id == Id).ToString()` ? What SQL query it will display?

Comment: from your explanation it seems like you expect a result from the insert from the other table, but is this the result? Based on your story, I think your insert may go wrong (inserting the same date every time).

Comment: @DmitryPavliv I can extract the Query on the Locals window while debugging, after executing it on SQL server it returns expected results, but on doing .ToList(), in the Locals window, it returns unexpected results.

Comment: @NielsdeSchrijver I am sorry, there was a typo in the first table, for rows with Id = 2, I fixed it, anyway it's a representation of my real data, I cannot post real data given that this is for my job

Comment: The error is either in the insert or in what you do with the results of the query. It is not posted here. Try to set the debugger to break on the closing `}` of GetData

Comment: Insertion in the history table is ok, because when I execute the Query extracted from the Locals window while debugging, results are as  expected.

Comment: can you show your `MyTable` class?

Comment: I have a feeling this is going to be caused by the change tracker "grouping" by an entity's PK (thereby effectively overwriting the same item several times), which in this case is not unique. EF has a habit of guessing that `Id` is the PK when the PK is not explicitly specified, and I assume that the change trackers tracks every object it instantiates (even when instantiating a result set) on the same PK value.

Comment: To test my idea: when you insert the items, do you insert them in separate contexts? (you didn't post that code) What happens when you add three items (with the same id) and only then save all three of them at the same time?

Comment: Post (a summary of) `MyModel`. I am with @Flater (hoi Guust), you probably have duplicate PKs in memory.

Comment: @Flater, the insertion process, was not done by me, I will ask my teammate what he has done. But this insertion is like a process which is executed once a day at 6:00 and it only inserts one record with same Id a day.

Comment: @DmitryPavliv and bommelding  I edited my post with the model

Comment: You should create primary key for MyModel class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[Index(IsUnique = false)]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

This does not prevent Id from being the Primary Key. If it did you would have seen another error, EF demands a PK on your classes.

You have only added an extra Index on the Id column. Not removed the PK constraint.

So our first suspicions appear to be right, you load a bunch of records with duplicate PK values in memory.  When you try `SaveChanges()` you will get an error or lose data.

A simple fix would look like

```
public class MyModel
{
    [Key]
    public int ModelId { get; set; }  // auto filled, ignore where you don't need it

    //[Index(IsUnique = false)] -- not needed
    public int Id { get; set; }       
    public DateTime Date{ get; set; }
    ...
```